# Is it possible to create typings, where function return value is selected by the string literal of function parameter

Tags: typescript, plugins

I've been trying to figure out how to implement typings for plugin based system, where base code actually doesn't know all the typings that system supports after some plugins has been loaded in.

I have tried to implement this by allowing plugins to declare ambient typings and extend that way original interfaces.

I hoped that with some string matching magic I could make it work a bit similar way with this:

```
type t1 = {
  type: 'foo';
  test: number;
};

type t2 = {
  type: 'bar';
  test: string;
};

type t = t1 | t2;

const tx1: t = {
  type: 'foo',
  test: 1
};

const tx2: t = {
  type: 'foo',
  test: 'this fails, because if type = foo, then test must be a number'
};

const txbar: t = {
  type: 'bar',
  test: 'this works because with bar object test can be string'
};
```

So for the plugin system I would like to implement same kind of string matching possibility, but with using interfaces:

```
interface PluginClass1 {}
interface PluginClass2 {}

interface PluginApi {
  getPlugin: (pluginName: 'plug1') => PluginClass1
}

interface PluginApi {
  getPlugin: (pluginName: 'plug2') => PluginClass2
}

class PluginManager implements PluginApi {
  plugins = {};
  getPlugin(pluginName) {
    return <any> this.plugins[pluginName];
  }
}

const manager = new PluginManager();

// here I would like to get correctly typed return value 
// according to name string (this doesn't work though)
const plugin1 = manager.getPlugin('plug1');
const plugin2 = manager.getPlugin('plug2');
```

Is there any way to make this kind of typing scheme to work or is there some better way for typing extendable interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The super easy solution: Manually declare that manager is a plugin api:

`const manager: PluginApi = new PluginManager()`

Then `plugin1` and `plugin2` will correctly be inferred to be `PluginClass1` and `PluginClass2` respectively.

*EDIT: In the above solution, you may also want to declare each `getPlugin` signature as a method, not a function assigned to a property. Eg: `getPlugin(pluginName: 'plug1'): PluginClass1` instead of `getPlugin: (pluginName: 'plug1') => PluginClass1`. That way you can take advantage of function overloading.*

However, if you don't want to declare every usage of `PluginManager` as a `PluginApi`, you'll have to make sure that the actual `getPlugin` implementation has the correct types (since typescript won't do this for you, although I'm not sure why not). So you need to give it the correct type signature manually. One way to do this is with a mapped type. But do do this, each plugin needs to declare its name and return type (instead of declaring the method signature itself).

```
interface PluginClass1 {}
interface PluginClass2 {}

// Note that each plugin now extends a different interface.  One that declares
// the name and return type, rather than the method signature.
interface PluginApiTypes {
  'plug1': PluginClass1
}

interface PluginApiTypes {
  'plug2': PluginClass2
}

// Then we combine all those names and return types into a method:
interface PluginApi {
    getPlugin<K extends keyof PluginApiTypes>(pluginName: K): PluginApiTypes[K];
}

class PluginManager implements PluginApi {
  plugins = {};
  // Unfortunatly we have to replicate the signature of getPlugin here,  since typescript will not infer it.
  getPlugin<K extends keyof PluginApiTypes>(pluginName: K): PluginApiTypes[K] {
    return <any> this.plugins[pluginName];
  }
}

const manager = new PluginManager();

// Now should be correctly inferred.
const plugin1 = manager.getPlugin('plug1');
const plugin2 = manager.getPlugin('plug2');
```

It's perhaps not an ideal solution, but it does work. Maybe someone more knowledgable than I can shed some light on why the type signature of `getPlugin` isn't inferred from the interface.

Comment: Thanks! This solution looks like something I can make to work also in my actual case. I would never have figured this out myself :) I had never seen `keyof`declarations either.